# Spark cannot see hive external table

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hive, emr

I am a noobie in Spark and AWS.

I have a DynamoDB table in AWS. I created a Spark cluster on EMR with hive.
With hive shell I created external table “RawData” to connect to DynamoDB.

Now when I start spark-shell with DynamoDB dependency jars `--jars /usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hive.jar,/usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hadoop.jar`
I can query the table “RawData” with HiveContext 
and get result.
 But when I submitting my Spark program with spark-submit I see in terminal some spark exception and in the logs I found: "**org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: no such table RawData**".

This is how I create a cluster: `aws emr create-cluster --name MyCluster --release-label emr-4.0.0 --applications Name=Spark Name=Hive ...`

Please advice what I’m doing wrong.
Lev

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found what was missing in the submit command.
I had to add `--files /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml` as one of the arguments of spark-submit.